# How to pass a specific post id from "all posts" list in Admin panel

Tags: admin

I want to add a custom column to the "all posts" list display in admin. I can add the custom column but my problem is I don't know how to tie the post ID to each listing on the page.
The custom column will contain a hyperlink to a php file that will display details about each particular post in the list.

Example POST 123

<a href="myphpcode.php?post=123" >Show Details</a>

Can I use $post->ID or something like that to get the post ID into the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've added the column correctly and not hacked it in somehow, then the `manage_${post_type}_posts_custom_column` filter should do what you want. The example in the Codex is about the best I've got given the sparcity of information in the question:

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_columns', 10, 2 );

function custom_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
    case 'book_author' :
        $terms = get_the_term_list( $post_id , 'book_author' , '' , ',' , '' );
            if ( is_string( $terms ) )
            echo $terms;
        else
            _e( 'Unable to get author(s)', 'your_text_domain' );
        break;

    case 'publisher' :
        echo get_post_meta( $post_id , 'publisher' , true ); 
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that the second parameter passed through the filter is your post ID.

Comment: Thanks, I found the code to add the link using your example.